# Pyspark with error self._sock.recv_into(b) socket.timeout: timed out

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

The goal is to use a UDF to categorize rows. I am using pyspark on windows.

Using simple functions or operations like filter appear to work.

Any direction on how to address the timeout/socket failure would be helpful (see error below).

There are no nulls in the data.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType,StringType

def BreakDown(arr_value):
    start_year = arr_value[0]
    start_month = arr_value[1]
    end_year = arr_value[2]
    end_month = arr_value[3]
    curr_year = arr_value[4]
    curr_month = arr_value[5]
    if   (curr_year == start_year) & (curr_month >= start_month) : return 1
    elif   (curr_year == end_year) & (curr_month <= end_month) : return 1
    elif   (curr_year > start_year) & (curr_year < end_year) : return 1
    else: return 0

    
udfBreakDown = udf(BreakDown, IntegerType())

temp = temp.withColumn('include', udfBreakDown(F.struct('start_year','start_month','end_year','end_month','curr_year','curr_month')))
```

> PythonException:    An exception was thrown from the Python worker.
> Please see the stack trace below. Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "E:\spark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py",
> line 585, in main   File
> "E:\spark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py",
> line 593, in read_int
> length = stream.read(4)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
> return self._sock.recv_into(b) socket.timeout: timed out

Comment: You don’t need UDF here, use when function.

Comment: It works on a linux machine. And I 'd rather write a readable udf  - especially as the conditions increase.

Comment: UDFs are known for bad performances in pyspark. Please don’t use them unless there is no spark builtin function for what you want to achieve. For readability you can also write wrapper function that returns a when column expression.

Comment: Ok  - Let me try as you suggest.

Comment: Sir BlackBishop - can confirm that when works, with no breakdowns in place of udf. Please include as answer for me to accept. Is it generally possible to configure the wiat time though, in case I run into this again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always avoid using UDFs when you can use Spark built-in functions. You can rewrite your logic using `when` function like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def get_include_col():
    c = F.when((F.col("curr_year") == F.col("start_year")) & (F.col("curr_month") >= F.col("start_month")), F.lit(1)) \
        .when((F.col("curr_year") == F.col("end_year")) & (F.col("curr_month") <= F.col("end_month")), F.lit(1)) \
        .when((F.col("curr_year") > F.col("start_year")) & (F.col("curr_year") < F.col("end_year")), F.lit(1)) \
        .otherwise(F.lit(0))
    return c


temp = temp.withColumn('include', get_include_col())
```

You can also use `functools.reduce` to dynamically generate the when expressions without having to tape all of them. For example:

```
import functools
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

cases = [
    ("curr_year = start_year and curr_month >= start_month", 1),
    ("curr_year = end_year and curr_month <= end_month", 1),
    ("curr_year > start_year and curr_year < end_year", 1)
]

include_col = functools.reduce(
    lambda acc, x: acc.when(F.expr(x[0]), F.lit(x[1])),
    cases,
    F
).otherwise(F.lit(0))

temp = temp.withColumn('include', include_col)
```